# What do you call an out-of-schedule speech in a conference?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

In some conferences there may be some out-of-schedule guest who has some valuable insights to share with the attendees (e.g. some government official or member of a legislative authority) who is allowed to address the audience with a short speech to present the above-mentioned insights.

What is the proper way to describe that kind of speech in English? Is there a standardized phrase or word for such things? The equivalent in some other languages is something like "intervention" but it doesn't sound correct to me in English.

Comment: It's an unscheduled speech, but 'unscheduled speaker' is probably more idiomatic.

Comment: off-the-cuff remarks

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in the Greek language there is this word "παρέμβαση" which literally translates to intervention to describe this, emphasizing on the "disruption" and not the "unscheduled" character of it. I was wondering if there is something similar in English.

Comment: There's 'impromptu', but that rather strongly suggests that the speaker just _decides_ to stand up and give a speech.

Comment: I would say *add-on* speaker, but I'm having trouble finding a good source for that.

Comment: To report neutrally, you would avoid the terms out-of-schedule, disruption, or intervention.  Could even call them surprise speakers. Maybe you don't have to report on the spontaneity at all, and call them speakers.

Comment: If the short speech is directly related to what went on immediately before it (e.g. it corrects a mistake in the preceding presentation, or provides a crucial detail that was missing in it), then *intervention* would be OK. If the speech is by somebody who was explicitly criticised in the preceding presentation, it could be called a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Extempore/extemporaneous/extemporary,"** **"spontaneous,"** **"unpremeditated,"** **"unplanned,"** and their synonyms can accomplish this task.

---

**"Extempore," "extemporaneous," and "extemporary"** are all defined as:

> Spoken or done without preparation. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/extempore)]

These three are the *most* fitting words for this situation.  In fact, the example sentence from [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/extempore)] for "extempore" is: "an extempore speech."

---

**"Spontaneous"** is defined as:

> Performed or occurring as a result of a sudden inner impulse or inclination and without premeditation or external stimulus. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/spontaneous)]

---

**"Unpremeditated"** is defined as:

> (of an act, remark, or state) not thought out or planned beforehand. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unpremeditated)]

---

**"Unplanned"** is (self-evidently) defined as:

> Not planned.

***Note:** although "impromptu" does apply to this situation, for some it a negative connotation (as Edwin Ashworth pointed out), so I would probably use one of the adjectives I have listed above instead.*

Comment: Most of these answers focus on the perspective of the person giving the short speech. My impression, though, is that the OP is looking at the matter from the perspective of the organisers of the conference. A speech that the organisers have not planned for (i.e. it is not listed on the announced schedule) and that they allow to be given only at the last moment, may, in fact, have been carefully planned, and indeed premeditated, by the person who is about to give it; it needn't be at all extemporaneous. On the other side, a scheduled speech may be given extemporaneously.

Comment: @jsw29 That is a good point; the speaker may have planned it, but the organizers may have been unaware of it.  Nonetheless, I think all of these adjectives (potentially with the exception of "premeditated") could still be used by the organizers to describe the speech.

Comment: If the unscheduled speaker pulls out the previously prepared notes and proceeds to speak on the basis of them, the speech wouldn't be extemporaneous.

Comment: @jsw29 That would only be true from the speaker's point of view.  However, the organizers could view it as the following: the speech was spoken without being prepared by the organizers.  Allow me to elaborate (because that might be a little cryptic).  The organizers likely had to prepare (in some way—maybe by setting up a podium or microphone) for the planned speakers, so the spontaneous/extemporary speech could be seen as not prepared by the organizers.  Please let me know if I need to elucidate further.

Comment: I see now what the source of the misunderstanding is. What you say is indeed correct according to the quoted definition of *extemporaneous*. The most usual use of that word, though, is for the speeches in which one formulates each sentence as one goes along, in contrast to the speeches that are read from notes or that have been previously memorised.

Comment: @jsw29 I agree with you.  The quoted definition does make the usage possible when looking at it from the organizers' perspective.  However, it probably isn't the best choice.  If F1234K meant to talk about it from the speaker's perspective (which is how I interpreted their question), then "extemporary" (and its variants) is likely the best choice.

Comment: It may be planned, by both the speaker and the organizers, but *unscheduled* formally.